# Why can't I see eth0 on my ubuntu 12.04 server in virtualbox?

Tags: 12.04, networking, virtualbox, ip-address

I've just install ubuntu 12.04 server on virtualbox through my windows 7 pc. When I try to give my server an ip address through /etc/network/inferfaces, I first to need make sure eth0 is there correct? And when I check for eth0, I don't have one when I go through ifconfig. I only see lo and virbr0. Commands like auto eth0 doesn't work. I'm a total newb to linux command system. Someone please enlighten me.

Answer (score 1):

The `virbr0`, or "Virtual Bridge 0" interface is used for NAT (Network Address Translation). This is the default network interface automatically set up by VirtualBox.

In order to have `eth0` available in your guest OS please follow this procedure:

- Select your guest virtual machine in the VirtualBox Manager then click on Settings.
- Select the Network category
- Select "Bridged Adapter" in the "Attached to" drop-down list.
- Boot your VM normally

[image]

Comment: I don't see eth0 in that box. I only see Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller and TAP-Windows Adaptor V9.

Comment: TAP-Windows Adapter V9 is virtual network connection for Open VPN. So I guess that you need to bridge your Realtek device